# mipmap and drawable folders

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-mipmap

I am new. I have two questions:

1. If I put an image in drawable it is assumed to be in mdpi but if my app runs in a xxhdpi device the app stop What happend?
2. To solve 1. I put the image in mipmap/xxhdpi (only in xxhdpi folder) and now not problem with xxhdpi device but in a hdpi tablet (too big) the image looks wrong (ugly) What can I do to solve that problem?

this is how it looks in tablet
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmysS.jpg)

Comment: I hope this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25234621/why-the-icons-images-looks-blur-not-clear-on-tablet-but-looks-fine-on-phon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add all .png images to

```
1. drawable-hdpi
2. drawable-mdpi
3. drawable-xhdpi
4. drawable-xxhdpi
```

it automatically suits too all devices where it is run!

Comment: if I put the images in all this folder the app size would be very higth?

Comment: The app size would increase. You could use `splits` in the gradle to specify the screen size.

Comment: There will be 2.31mb difference in app size if you manage to use drawables. this is not much when the app is worth

Comment: but I have 30 other images with the same problem

Comment: then compress your pictures in Photoshop or compressjpeg.com in this link.. but there is not other ways than not doing this.

Comment: thank you it works

Comment: Then put up vote) welcome

Answer (score 0):

**Answer** 
1. `mipmap-` folders are for `ic_launcher.png` images (launcher icons).
2. Android system finds images in it's matching-density-folder first, and if it can't find the image in it's matching-density-folder, then it finds image from the closest-matching-density-folder and
If the image is smaller then density, it will expand, the other case, it will downsize the image.

So in the meantime, system uses too much memory for loading images, and that's why the app crashes. It may be boring job to put images in each density folders but you gotta do that work for the system.

**Better solutuon**
You can use 9-patch images or Vector(svg) images.

- You can put 9-patch images just like other images into each density-folder.
- Vector(svg) images, you can put them through this >> `right click on res/drawable > new > Vector Asset > select 'Local file' > Finish`

**Tip**
1. Use JPEG format images they are the smallest and good enough quality for apps.
2. If it's possible, make SVG file and put it in to `drawable` folder only once. That will be the most efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem you should put the image in respective drawable folders according to mobile device’s screen resolutions.
Below are the screen resolutions with reference to the device name.

**Screen Resolutions:**

```
480x800 - drawable-hdpi - Sony Expedia
600x1024 - drawable-large-hdpi - Samsung tab2
720x1280 - drawable-xhdpi - Samsung s3
800x1280 - drawable-large-tvdpi - Nexus 7 tab
1080x1920 - drawable-xxhdpi - S4,Nexus5
1200x1920 - drawable-large-xhdpi - New nexus 7
1440X2560 - drawable-xxxhdpi - Nexus 6,Samsung S6edge
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a nine-patch image that would give u an image for all the drawable sizes

Answer (score -1):

Add all images to

```
drawable-hdpi
drawable-mdpi
drawable-xhdpi
drawable-xxhdpi
```

or

```
mipmap-hdpi
drawable-mdpi
drawable-xhdpi
drawable-xxhdpi
```

and it will automatically suits to all devices.

and if image is too large then you can 
also covert that image into tiny image and then put that image in to

```
drawable-nodpi
```

it will also reduce apk size and suits to all devices,and of course you can also use nine-patch images it will give you all drawable sizes images.

Hope that it helps you.

Comment: thanks, how do i put the image in drawable-nodpi

Comment: covert your image into tinyPNG,here is the link 
https://tinypng.com/
then put it into drawable-nodpi folder then you will not need to put it into other folders